# How to get only "text" filed from JSON server response?

Tags: android, json, node.js

I'm receiving server response as JSON format, and need to get only field "text" and store it in arraylist. I tried but am getting only first text field as show below output, but i need all the text fields in evidencelist json object.Can anyone help me here to get all the text fields ?

Android code:

```
 HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity(); // wait for response
            // convert response to a string and log it
            if (entity != null) {

                                    //Toast.makeText(RegistartionPage.this,
                      //  "Inside If", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        //.show();
            InputStream inputstream = entity.getContent();
            BufferedReader bufferedreader =
            new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputstream));
            StringBuilder stringbuilder = new StringBuilder();
            String currentline = null;
            while ((currentline = bufferedreader.readLine()) != null) {
                //Toast.makeText(RegistartionPage.this,
                       // "Inside while", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                       // .show();
            stringbuilder.append(currentline + "\n");
            }
            String result = stringbuilder.toString();
            Log.v("HTTP REQUEST",result);
            inputstream.close();

            ids=result;

            }
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(ids);
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                 JSONObject c = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                 String question1 = c.getString("question");
                 JSONObject object2 = new JSONObject(question1);
                 JSONArray jArray1 = object2.getJSONArray("evidencelist");
                 //String comp_id = jArray1.optString();
                 for(int j = 0; j < jArray1 .length(); j++)
                 {
                    JSONObject object3 = jArray1.getJSONObject(j);
                    text = object3.getString("text");
                    /*num = object3.getInt("value");*/

                 }
            }
```

JSON output from server:

```
09-19 17:00:41.182: V/HTTP REQUEST(1539): [
09-19 17:00:41.182: V/HTTP REQUEST(1539):  {
09-19 17:00:41.182: V/HTTP REQUEST(1539):   "question": {
09-19 17:00:41.182: V/HTTP REQUEST(1539):    "qclasslist": [
09-19 17:00:41.182: V/HTTP REQUEST(1539):     {
09-19 17:00:41.182: V/HTTP REQUEST(1539):      "value": "FACTOID"
09-19 17:00:41.182: V/HTTP REQUEST(1539):     },
09-19 17:00:41.182: V/HTTP REQUEST(1539):     {
09-19 17:00:41.182: V/HTTP REQUEST(1539):      "value": "DESCRIPTIVE"
09-19 17:00:41.182: V/HTTP REQUEST(1539):     }
09-19 17:00:41.182: V/HTTP REQUEST(1539):    ],
09-19 17:00:41.182: V/HTTP REQUEST(1539):    "focuslist": [
09-19 17:00:41.182: V/HTTP REQUEST(1539):     {
09-19 17:00:41.182: V/HTTP REQUEST(1539):      "value": "What"
09-19 17:00:41.182: V/HTTP REQUEST(1539):     }
09-19 17:00:41.182: V/HTTP REQUEST(1539):    ],
09-19 17:00:41.182: V/HTTP REQUEST(1539):    "latlist": [
09-19 17:00:41.182: V/HTTP REQUEST(1539):     {
09-19 17:00:41.182: V/HTTP REQUEST(1539):      "value": "HIV"
09-19 17:00:41.182: V/HTTP REQUEST(1539):     }
09-19 17:00:41.182: V/HTTP REQUEST(1539):    ],
09-19 17:00:41.182: V/HTTP REQUEST(1539):    "evidencelist": [
09-19 17:00:41.182: V/HTTP REQUEST(1539):     {
09-19 17:00:41.182: V/HTTP REQUEST(1539):      "value""0.90134596824646",
09-19 17:00:41.182: V/HTTP REQUEST(1539):      "text": "HIV stands for human immunodeficiency virus. This is the virus that causes AIDS. There is no cure yet for HIV/AIDS, but there are treatments that can help people live longer, healthier lives.",
09-19 17:00:41.182: V/HTTP REQUEST(1539):      "id": "PB_472D471A96B201B91949C3B1C28D468B",
09-19 17:00:41.182: V/HTTP REQUEST(1539):      "title": "Get Tested for HIV : Get Tested for HIV : The Basics : What is HIV?",
09-19 17:00:41.182: V/HTTP REQUEST(1539):      "document":"http://10.110.76.161:8080/instance/67/deepqa/v1/question/document/PB_472D471A96B201B91949C3B1C28D468B/175/3441" (http://10.110.76.161:8080/instance/67/deepqa/v1/question/document/PB_472D471A96B201B91949C3B1C28D468B/175/3441%27) ,
09-19 17:00:41.182: V/HTTP REQUEST(1539):      "copyright": "No copyright specified for this supporting passage or document.",
09-19 17:00:41.182: V/HTTP REQUEST(1539):      "termsOfUse": "No license specified for this supporting passage or document.",
09-19 17:00:41.182: V/HTTP REQUEST(1539):      "metadataMap": {
09-19 17:00:41.182: V/HTTP REQUEST(1539):       "abstract": "Protect yourself and others from HIV and other STDs.",
09-19 17:00:41.182: V/HTTP REQUEST(1539):       "originalfile": "Get Tested for HIV.html",
09-19 17:00:41.182: V/HTTP REQUEST(1539):       "title": "Get Tested for HIV : Get Tested for HIV : The Basics : What is HIV?",
 09-19 17:00:41.182: V/HTTP REQUEST(1539):       "corpusName": "PB",
 09-19 17:00:41.182: V/HTTP REQUEST(1539):       "description": "Protect yourself and others from HIV and other STDs.",
 09-19 17:00:41.182: V/HTTP REQUEST(1539):       "deepqaid": "33646738",
 09-19 17:00:41.182: V/HTTP REQUEST(1539):       "fileName": "/watsondata/ingestion/14d9d1d3b23/working/201505290044/eng/di/output/trec/intermediate/xml-splitTrecTrim/33646738.xml",
 09-19 17:00:41.182: V/HTTP REQUEST(1539):       "DOCNO": "472D471A96B201B91949C3B1C28D468B"
 09-19 17:00:41.182: V/HTTP REQUEST(1539):      }
 09-19 17:00:41.182: V/HTTP REQUEST(1539):     },
 09-19 17:00:41.182: V/HTTP REQUEST(1539):     {
 09-19 17:00:41.182: V/HTTP REQUEST(1539):      "value":"0.06850375980138779",
 09-19 17:00:41.182: V/HTTP REQUEST(1539):      "text": "Breastfeeding, pregnancy, or childbirth if the mother has HIV. Getting a transfusion of blood that's infected with HIV (very rare in the United States). Learn more about HIV/AIDS: What is HIV/AIDS? Women and HIV/AIDS. Take Action! Pages: 1 2 3 4 5 6 >.",
09-19 17:00:41.182: V/HTTP REQUEST(1539):      "id":"PB_472D471A96B201B944EEF8045EC5E0AF",
09-19 17:00:41.182: V/HTTP REQUEST(1539):      "title": "Get Tested for HIV : Get Tested for HIV : The Basics : How do people get HIV?",
09-19 17:00:41.182: V/HTTP REQUEST(1539):      "document":"http://10.110.76.161:8080/instance/67/deepqa/v1/question/document/PB_472D471A96B201B944EEF8045EC5E0AF/473/725" (http://10.110.76.161:8080/instance/67/deepqa/v1/question/document/PB_472D471A96B201B944EEF8045EC5E0AF/473/725%27) ,
09-19 17:00:41.182: V/HTTP REQUEST(1539):      "copyright": "No copyright specified for this supporting passage or document.",
09-19 17:00:41.182: V/HTTP REQUEST(1539):      "termsOfUse": "No license specified for this supporting passage or document.",
09-19 17:00:41.182: V/HTTP REQUEST(1539):      "metadataMap": {
09-19 17:00:41.182: V/HTTP REQUEST(1539):       "abstract": "Protect yourself and others from HIV and other STDs.",
09-19 17:00:41.182: V/HTTP REQUEST(1539):       "originalfile": "Get Tested for HIV.html",
09-19 17:00:41.182: V/HTTP REQUEST(1539):       "title": "Get Tested for HIV : Get Tested for HIV : The Basics : How do people get HIV?",
09-19 17:00:41.182: V/HTTP REQUEST(1539):       "corpusName": "PB",
09-19 17:00:41.182: V/HTTP REQUEST(1539):       "description": "Protect yourself and others from HIV and other STDs.",
09-19 17:00:41.182: V/HTTP REQUEST(1539):       "deepqaid": "33646739",
09-19 17:00:41.182: V/HTTP REQUEST(1539):       "fileName": "/watsondata/ingestion/14d9d1d3b23/working/201505290044/eng/di/output/trec/intermediate/xml-splitTrecTrim/33646739.xml",
09-19 17:00:41.182: V/HTTP REQUEST(1539):       "DOCNO": "472D471A96B201B944EEF8045EC5E0AF"
09-19 17:00:41.182: V/HTTP REQUEST(1539):      }
09-19 17:00:41.182: V/HTTP REQUEST(1539):     },
09-19 17:00:41.182: V/HTTP REQUEST(1539):     {
09-19 17:00:41.182: V/HTTP REQUEST(1539):      "value":"0.03481652960181236",
09-19 17:00:41.182: V/HTTP REQUEST(1539):      "text": "See a doctor right away if you have unprotected anal or vaginal sex with someone who might be HIV-positive. Taking medication within 3 days (known as post-exposure prophylaxis or PEP) can dramatically reduce the chance of getting HIV. Talk to your doctor about HIV medication to prevent HIV infection (known as pre-exposure prophylaxis or PrEP) if you often have unprotected anal or vaginal sex. If you are HIV-positive, tell your sex partners you have HIV before you have sex with them and take steps to prevent transmitting HIV to others.",
 09-19 17:00:41.182: V/HTTP REQUEST(1539):      "id": "PB_8C42FE3B49104EC939E170D23ADBCDD7",
 09-19 17:00:41.182: V/HTTP REQUEST(1539):      "title": "National Latino AIDS Awareness Day : National Latino AIDS Awareness Day : National Latino AIDS Awareness Day :What Can You Do?",
 09-19 17:00:41.182: V/HTTP REQUEST(1539):      "document":"http://10.110.76.161:8080/instance/67/deepqa/v1/question/document/PB_8C42FE3B49104EC939E170D23ADBCDD7/1379/1919" (http://10.110.76.161:8080/instance/67/deepqa/v1/question/document/PB_8C42FE3B49104EC939E170D23ADBCDD7/1379/1919%27) ,
09-19 17:00:41.182: V/HTTP REQUEST(1539):      "copyright": "No copyright specified for this supporting passage or document.",
09-19 17:00:41.182: V/HTTP REQUEST(1539):      "termsOfUse": "No license specified for this supporting passage or document.",
09-19 17:00:41.182: V/HTTP REQUEST(1539):      "metadataMap": {
09-19 17:00:41.182: V/HTTP REQUEST(1539):       "abstract": "HIV continues to threaten the health of Hispanic and Latinos in the United States. CDC
09-19 17:00:41.249: I/Choreographer(1539): Skipped 12476 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Comment: https://github.com/mohit008/Android-Json-Example

Comment: yes, I'm able to get first text field i.e. HIV Stands for human, but i have 3 text fields in loop. Remaining 2 text fields not able to get.

Comment: have you checked my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this..

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(ids);
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
     JSONObject ques_obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

     JSONObject question = ques_obj.getJSONObject("question");

     JSONArray q = question.getJSONArray("qclasslist");
     JSONArray f = question.getJSONArray("focuslist");
     JSONArray l = question.getJSONArray("latlist");

     for (int a = 0; a < q.length(); a++) {
         JSONObject q_obj = q.getJSONObject(a);
         text = q_obj .getString("value");
     }
     for (int b = 0; b < f.length(); b++) {
         JSONObject f_obj = f.getJSONObject(b);
         text = f_obj.getString("value");

     }   

     for (int c = 0; c < l.length(); c++) {
         JSONObject l_obj = l.getJSONObject(c);

         text =  l_obj.getString("value");
     }   

     JSONArray jArray1 = question.getJSONArray("evidencelist");

     for(int d = 0; d < jArray1 .length(); d++)
     {
        JSONObject object3 = jArray1.getJSONObject(d);
        text = object3.getString("text");
     }
}
```

Comment: yeah, but i got this error
09-29 19:42:48.620: W/System.err(3090): org.json.JSONException: No value for value
09-29 19:42:48.621: W/System.err(3090):  at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:389)
09-29 19:42:48.622: W/System.err(3090):  at org.json.JSONObject.getString(JSONObject.java:550)

Comment: i have edited the answer now check if there is any error ?

Comment: now, 
09-29 20:04:22.350: W/System.err(3147): org.json.JSONException: No value for evidencelist
09-29 20:04:22.363: W/System.err(3147):  at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:389)

Comment: Got null pointer exception
09-29 20:18:14.814: W/System.err(3202): java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
09-29 20:18:14.821: W/System.err(3202):  at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
09-29 20:18:14.821: W/System.err(3202):  at android.util.Log.v(Log.java:118)

Comment: Actually my code was working, but i forgot to store text strings into Arraylist <String> . Anyway It worked Thank you